# Java - method to lookup a specific ID from txt file and return that line details

Tags: java, oop, file-io

I am writing a method to lookup a specific ID that is stored within a txt file.

These details are assigned to an arrayList titled list, if the lookup string matches the data stored in list then it reads the id,firstname,surname (IE the whole line of the txt file) and then creates an instance of another class profile.

I then want to add this lookup data to a new arrayList titled lookup then to output it. I have the below method however, it does not work and just jumps to my else clause. 
Could anyone tell me where i'm going wrong and how to fix would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: An `ArrayList<Profile>` will never contain a `String IDlookup` as `Profile` and `String` are completly different data types

Comment: as @OHGODSPIDERS said you need compare type with type so you'll need to get the value of ID in your list to compare to IDlookup, you'll propably need a method in Profile to do this

Comment: @Fepapci Please don't remove all the code from your question and make it therfor useless for other readers. Also if an answer solved your problem you should accept it and maybe give the person an upvote for their efford.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead use a TupleMap for the same effect?

> // create our map Map peopleByForename
>   = new HashMap>();
>
> // populate it peopleByForename.put("Bob", new Tuple2(new Person("Bob
>   Smith",
>                                          new Person("Bob Jones"));
>
> // read from it Tuple bobs = peopleByForename["Bob"];
>   Person bob1 = bobs.Item1; Person bob2 = bobs.Item2;

Then an example of reading the key:value from the txt file can be found here : [Java read txt file to hashmap, split by ":"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061782/java-read-txt-file-to-hashmap-split-by) using Buffered Reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8, you can use Lambda to help you. Just replace this line:

```
    if(list.contains(IDlookup))
```

to this one:

```
    boolean containsId = list.stream().anyMatch((Profile p) -> p.getId().equals(IDlookup));
    if (containsId)
```