# How to correct use hashmap and properties in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I faced the next problem.
I have a .txt file, which contains data in the format:

> "name"="value"

True data as example:

```
counter=10
scheduleNewPeriodEnd=2100-12-31
scheduleNewPeriodStart=2100-01-01
```

And i took [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061782/java-read-txt-file-to-hashmap-split-by/29062869) as example and trying to convert it to hashmap with JSR223 Sampler or Beanshell Sampler. Then i want to put some value from map to properties for use it in next thread with requests:

```
    String filePath = "/soap/otherData.txt";
    String counter = ""; 
    String scheduleNewPeriodEnd = "";
    String scheduleNewPeriodStart = "";
    String arSchruleTypeId = "";
    String sarSchruleTypeId = "";

    HashMap map = new HashMap();
   
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] parts = line.split("=", 2);
        if (parts.length >= 2)
        {
            String key = parts[0];
            String value = parts[1];
            map.put(key, value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("ignoring line: " + line);
        }
    }
   
    counter = map.get("counter");
    scheduleNewPeriodStart = map.get("scheduleNewPeriodStart");
    scheduleNewPeriodEnd = map.get("scheduleNewPeriodEnd");
    arSchruleTypeId = map.get("arSchruleTypeId");
    sarSchruleTypeId = map.get("sarSchruleTypeId");

    props.put(schPerStart,  scheduleNewPeriodStart);
    
    reader.close();
```

But it doesn't work. When i want to see what is props contains - the actual result this:

```
log.info("Property schPerStart is:  " + props.get("schPerStart"));

INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: Property schPerStart is:  ${schStart}
```

Expected result should be:

```
INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: Property schPerStart is: 2100-01-01
```

So i haven't any variable with name ${schStart} and don't understand why JMeter put it into props.
The java code was tested in Idea and saving values to the map works correctly.
Is it i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved.
Problem was that i wrapped code into class and he didn't call there. I just deleted class and method wrappers and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the only line authored by you, just surround your `schPerStart` with quotation marks and the "code" should start working as you expect.

```
props.put("schPerStart",  scheduleNewPeriodStart);
```

Also be aware [that starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

You won't have to change a single line, just copy and paste the whole snippet into the relevant [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and enjoy (unless you would like to make your code more "[groovy](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/)")

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. This mistake was fixed too.